# How to code a class method which uses the object it was created in?

Tags: javascript

Maybe I'm overcomplicating, but I'm trying to write a class method which creates event listeners that fire off methods from the object they were created in.

```
class Example {
  constructor() {
  
    }

  dosomething(){}
  
  addListeners() {
    document.addEventListener('keypress', function (e) {
      if (e.key === 'Enter') {
        {HERE WE NEED A REFERENCE}.dosomething()
      }
    })
  }
}

const exampleObject = new Example()
exampleObject.addlisteners()

//*user presses Enter*
//exampleObject.dosomething() fires
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `this` to achieve that. Note that you need an arrow function to remain in the correct scope

```
class Example {

    constructor() {
  
    }

    dosomething(){}
  
    addListeners() {
      document.addEventListener('keypress', (e) => {
        if (e.key === 'Enter') {
          this.dosomething()
        }
      })
  }
}

const exampleObject = new Example()
exampleObject.addlisteners()
```

I find it a bit nicer to put the `if` in its own function :

```
   class Example {

        constructor() {
      
        }

        checkInput(e){
           if (e.key === 'Enter') {
              this.dosomething()
            }
        }
    
        dosomething(){}
      
        addListeners() {
          document.addEventListener('keypress', (e) => this.checkInput(e))
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to preserve the function syntax

Simply define the reference inside then addListeners before calling the document.addEventListener function

otherwise you can just use an arrow function instead

```js
class Example {
  constructor() {
    this.addListeners = this.addListeners.bind(this); // Binding
    this.dosomething = this.dosomething.bind(this);
    
  }

  dosomething(e){
    console.log("Refrence")
  }
  
  addListeners() {
    const ref = this;
    document.addEventListener('keypress', function (e) {
      if (e.key === 'Enter') {
          
        ref.dosomething(e)
      }
    })
  }
}

const exampleObject = new Example()

exampleObject.addListeners()
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `this` at the `constructor()` first, establish how DOM elements are collected. Treat each element as an object and have `this` point to them as a group:

**Figure I**

```js
constructor(selector) {
  const tags = document.querySelectorAll(selector);
  this.length = tags.length;
  Object.assign(this, tags);
}
```

First method should be responsible for passing in functions and reassigning `this` to each element of a group using `.call()` (return `this` so chaining is possible):

**Figure II**

```js
all(callback) {
  for (let tag of Array.from(this)) {
    callback.call(tag);
  }
  return this;
}
```

Now that the given callback's `this` is integrated by the `.all()` method, the next method will bind a given event to each element of a group:

**Figure III**

```js
on(event, callback, capture = false) {
  return this.all(function() {
    this.addEventListener(event, callback, capture);
  });
}
```

Click the tags in example to see that the events are registered.
See this [article](https://www.ericponto.com/blog/2014/10/05/es6-dom-library/) for a better explanation

**Details are commented in example**

```js
/** Class that binds multiple elements to events. */
class Binder {
  /**
   * Collect elements 
   * @param {string} selector - A CSS selector string
   */
  constructor(selector) {
    const tags = document.querySelectorAll(selector);
    this.length = tags.length;
    Object.assign(this, tags);
  }
  /** 
   * Bind a given callback to all elements of a group 
   * @param {function} callback - An event handler
   * @return {this} for chaining
   */
  all(callback) {
    for (let tag of Array.from(this)) {
      callback.call(tag);
    }
    return this;
  }
  /**
   * Bind a group to a given event
   * @param {event} event - The event to bind to
   * @param {function} callback - The event handler
   * @param {boolean} capture - true capture phase is listened on,
   *        false bubbling phase is listened on, @default is false.
   * @return {this} for chaining
   */
  on(event, callback, capture = false) {
    return this.all(function() {
      this.addEventListener(event, callback, capture);
    });
  }
}
// Instantiate with a function 
const _ = (selector) => new Binder(selector);

_('.text').on('click', log);
_('.color').on('click', hex);

// Callbacks log(e) and hex(e)
function log(e) {
  const clk = e.target;
  let text = clk.value.length > 0 ? clk.tagName+': '+clk.value : clk.tagName+': NO CONTENT';
  console.log(text);
}

function hex(e) {
  this.style.backgroundColor = "#" + Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16);
}
```

```css
output, 
data,
.color {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  outline: 1px dashed red;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input class='text' value='TestA'><br>
  <input class='text'><br>
  <textarea class='text color'>TestC</textarea><br>
  <output class='text'>TestD</output><br>
  <data class='text' value='TestE'>X</data>
</form>
<div class='color'>X</div>
```